# Magento 2 admin how to change product price when adding product to cart

Tags: magento2, php, sales-order, admin-order-create

Can any one please suggest me how to change the product price when adding product to cart through admin.

I want to change the price of the product programmatically when adding product to cart.

Answer (score 1):

Create **events.xml** in app/code/Vendor/Module/etc

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_quote_add_item">
        <observer name="customprice" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\CustomPrice" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Create **CustomPrice.php** in Vendor\Module\Observer

```
<?php

    namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

    use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\App\State;
    class CustomPrice implements ObserverInterface
    {
    protected $_state;
    public function __construct(State $state){

        $this->_state=$state;
    }

        public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
           if($this->_state->getAreaCode()=='adminhtml'){
            $item = $observer->getEvent()->getData('quote_item');         
            $price = 100; //set your price here
            $item->setCustomPrice($price);
            $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
            $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
        }
      }

    }
```